# PayPal Adaptive Payment Form Submission Bug

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have an online marketplace that utilizes the PayPal Adaptive Payments API (via PHP). My code has worked perfectly until the last few weeks (Jan 2017). Now, when a person clicks a Buy button on my site, they are directed to the PayPal home page instead of a PayPal payment screen, which interrupts the payment flow. If the user goes back and clicks Buy a second time, only *then* are they directed to PayPal's payment page. I haven't seen anything indicating an update to the API and I don't receive any error messages. Anyone else encountering this error?

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the exact same problem. All of a sudden the redirect lands the user in the homepage, instead of the checkout page. When retried the user lands in the checkout page.

Test: Grab the redirect URL. Paste it on a browser's address bar. If you end up getting redirected to homepage, paste the URL again and you will be redirected to checkout page now. Paste the URL again, and you will be redirected to homepage.

Comment: This one was so elementary it almost eluded me! The first parameter was being delimited with a & - which wasn't there before. I will find the culprit later.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=[appkey]

the first parameter needs to be delimited with a ? not an &. Please change it to ? and give it a try. I could not reproduce the problem after I changed it to ?.

Comment: Wow yes...that worked for me also! Good catch and thanks so much. I just wonder why PayPal changed this link and I wish I could know what changes they'll make in the future so this sort of thing doesn't happen again.